# Analysis of a non-recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I am working on a problem presented in Levitin and Levitin's book on algorithmic puzzles.

**Problem**: The algorithm starts with a single square and on each of its next iterations adds new squares all around the outside. How many unit squares will there be after the nth iteration?

**My problem**: I understand that after n iterations, the longest horizontal row will contain $(2n - 1)$ squares. The rows above and below it will contain an odd number of squares from $1$ to $(2n - 3)$. How can I use these facts and the fact that the sum of the first $n - 1$ odd numbers is equal to $(n - 1)^2$ to find the total number of squares? In other words, how can I combine these facts into a solution?

Comment: Are you talking about squares on an infinite sized checkerboard?  Or different sized squares?  It sounds you are just making a giant diamond.  Your algorithm is really ambiguously stated.

Comment: @DanielV Yes, a giant diamond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the diamond into a top half and a bottom half, and choose arbitrarily that the top half contains the middle row.

Then the number of squares in the top is the sum of the first $n$ odd integers, and the number of squares in the bottom is the first $n-1$ odd integers.  Add and simplify.

Comment: I took the number of squares on the top ($n^2$) and the number of squares on the bottom $(n-1)^2$ and ended up with $2n^2 -2n + 1$. Thanks for the explanation.